# Materialize button Text & icon vertical alignment mobile phonegap

Tags: cordova, button, materialize

I am building my android mobile app with Phonegap and using Materialize CSS. In Mobile device button text is not verticaly aligned.

[image]

Whereas in desktop window chrome browser the alignment is good. Refer the Login Buttons in the images. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Hi Prakash and welcome to StackOverflow. Please be more specific in asking your question. I cannot understand your issue either. 
It would also help big-time if you can provide the source and point out exactly what you need to do.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you have done. It would be more helpful to solve your problem.